# Return value from Private Method

Tags: java

Here i come... my question is when i have entered everything.. but the totalpages is not returning during the display..

```
private int totalPages () {
    totalPages = first.getPages() + second.getPages() + third.getPages();
    return totalPages;
}

//Make a subprogram to display the info of author, 
//title, year, and totalPages and return the values
public String printInfo () {
    String info = "Book Title: " + title + "\n";
    info += "Book Author: " + author + "\n";
    info += "Year: " + year + "\n";
    info += "Number of pages: " + totalPages + "\n";
    return info;
}
```

the output is 0... why??

Comment: Where do `first`, `second`, and `third` come from?

Comment: @LinCheng In StackOverflow if the answers helped you up vote the answers and if any answer solved your problem mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
the output is 0... why??
```

What you are actually returning is `info += "Number of pages: " + totalPages + "\n";` and `totalPages` looks like an instance variable to me 
 (since you have used it across methods). Instance variables get default values and and the default value is `0` for an integer. This is why you get `0`.

To get your desired value you have to call the method `totalPages()`. **Alternative** to above answer you may not even use the call in your concatenation. You can do

```
public String printInfo () {
    totalPages();
    String info = "Book Title: " + title + "\n";
    info += "Book Author: " + author + "\n";
    info += "Year: " + year + "\n";
    info += "Number of pages: " + totalPages + "\n";
    return info;
}
```

Also I would suggest dont just keep using `+` operator. Rather use a `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer`.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't calling the `totalPages()` method

```
info += "Number of pages: " + totalPages() + "\n";
```

Comment: oh i see... but since i ady return the value totalPage... why cant i use the variable... just curious... could u pls explain? thk in advance

Comment: @PM77-1 Yes. I hope he has declared totalPages, first, second, and third variables in the code

Comment: i have ady declared it in the early... for example, i declared it into private int totalPage, private Chapter first, private Chapter second, private Chapter third... is it the reason i cant use?

Comment: assuming that totalPages=0 and in your printinfo you didnt call the method totalPages() the totalPages variable will remain 0; because you didnt do any operation for it to change @LinCheng

Comment: @LinCheng You are assigning the value to the totalPages variable inside the totalPages() method. Therefore if you are not calling that method your variable is having it default value. Default value of instance int variable is 0.

Comment: @Kerppag oh i see... now i understand... thk for teaching...!! appreciate... :D

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne yeah... i know! tq!!